# Saving data inside for iterator with async mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

So here I have a array and I want to loop through it and save each object inside it in `mongo` but when ever I do this nothing happen because mongoose is `async` module so I want to solve this problem with `async` library how can I use this libraries in order to solve this problem
here is my node js code :

```
for(var index in sample){
   var temp = new db.collection_Name(sample[index]);
   temp.save()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [async module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) it would look something like this:

```
var async = require('async');

async.each(samples, function(sample, next) {
  var temp = new db.collection_name(sample);
  temp.save(function(err, doc) {
    next();
  });
}, function() {
  console.log('all done!');
});
```